# selenium java collections to filter rows of data in excel against the zip code (many to many mapping)

Tags: java, excel

We are having rows of data contains customer details that mapped to zip code. The list contains 40k rows of data in many to many mapping.

I would like to filter the matching "customer details - rows" based on the zip code that i give as input.

Kindly suggest selenium java collections way of filtering excel(source data) that provide customer info against the given zip code and that can be used to validate if the front end UI filtering is correct.

Comment: Do you know what is Selenium?

Comment: @Guy do you want to humiliate me, its something through Selenium APIs want to validate this scenario using java collections library. Do you have answer to my question.

Pls let me know If i need to add more information

Comment: Selenium is a tool for websites interaction, there is no connection to excel. And you are expected to try yourself before posting a question here, if you did please post your code. You should also explain better what you are trying to do, currently it's very unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I really havent tried, looking for ideas how to perform this validation. I am trying to validate the UI results for the zipcode against the sourec date thats available in the excel sheet.

@Guy pls throw some light here, will try and get back to you with the code